# Adjust containerView Height based on PageviewController

Tags: ios, swift

I'm kinda having a trouble adjusting the ContainerView height based on the height of the pageViewController.

So on this example I have two pages : "**Yellow Page**","**Purple Page**"

*Yellow page* = 120px Height

*Purple page* = 250px Height

All I wanna work out is to adjust the height automatically as I scroll on the pageViewController embedded on the containerView.

Hope you can help, thank you!

Here's the Image.
[Storyboard Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QJoGm.png)

This is my PageViewController Code.

```
import UIKit    

class PageViewController: UIPageViewController,UIPageViewControllerDataSource, UIPageViewControllerDelegate {


    func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerBefore viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {
        let currentIndex = pages.index(of: viewController)!
        let previousIndex = abs((currentIndex - 1) % pages.count)
        return pages[previousIndex]



    }

    func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerAfter viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {
        let currentIndex = pages.index(of: viewController)!
        let nextIndex = abs((currentIndex + 1) % pages.count)
        return pages[nextIndex]
    }

    var pages = [UIViewController]()
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()    

        self.delegate = self
        self.dataSource = self

        let page1: UIViewController! = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "page1");
        let page2: UIViewController! = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "page2");
        pages.append(page1)
        pages.append(page2)
        setViewControllers([page1], direction: UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirection.forward, animated: false, completion: nil)


    }

    func presentationCountForPageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController) -> Int {
        return pages.count
    }

    func presentationIndexForPageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController) -> Int {
        return 0
    }    

    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {


    }    



}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can hook the height of the container and controls it from the pager like this

```
@IBOutlet weak var conH: NSLayoutConstraint!
```

//

```
func callMe(value:CGFloat) {

    conH.constant = value

    self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
}
```

//

```
func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, didFinishAnimating finished: Bool, previousViewControllers: [UIViewController], transitionCompleted completed: Bool) {

    let vc = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController as! ViewController

    let currentIndex = pages.index(of: previousViewControllers.first!)!

    let nextIndex = abs((currentIndex + 1) % pages.count)

    vc.callMe(value:nextIndex == 0 ? 100 : 200)

}
```

//

[image]

Comment: Thank you! It worked, Problem is if i dragged the pager but did not fully go to the second page its still changing the height.